# Javascript regular expression numeric range

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone help with a regular expression. I'm trying to format a phone number and handle an range of extension digits.  I tried using a range [1-5], but that doesn't seem to work.

```
$(".phone").text(function(i, text) {
    if(text.length == 10) { //this portion works fine
        text = text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
        return text;
    }else if (text.length > 10) { //this is where I need help
        text = text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{[1-5]})/, "($1) $2-$3 x$4");
        return text;
    }
});
```

Is there a regular expression to handle a range of numbers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of {[1-5]} is invalid. { and } indicate that the number of matches is between the two numbers contained within it (either parameter can be omitted), whilst [1-5] matches one character out of 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. You need:

```
    text = text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{1,5})/, "($1) $2-$3 x$4");
```

instead. For more information, see [this QuickStart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) on repetition.

Comment: Happy to help! I've added a link to a guide that'll give more information if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, omit the square braces and use a comma.

```
\d{1,5}
```